# How to continuously receive data?

Tags: python, sockets

I've created a very simple tcp server in Python. I connect, then the server waits for data to be sent from the client, then the client waits for data to be sent back. While each is waiting, they aren't able to send data. So one side can't send two messages back to back. I'd like to for both sides to listen and still be able to send at all times.How would I go about that?
Server code:

```
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind((ipAddr, port))
print('Server starting on ' + ipAddr + ':' + str(port))
socket.listen(10)
print('Waiting for connection...')
c, addr = socket.accept()
print('Connection recieved from ' + str(addr))
while True:
    try:

        buf = c.recv(1024)
        if buf == 'stop':
            break
        elif len(buf) > 0:
            print(buf)
            response = input('>')
            c.sendall(str.encode(str(response)))
    except:
        print('Error')
        break

socket.close()
```

I'd like to be able to send back to back messages from the server to the client while still listening for responses from the client

Comment: One good way to do this is to set your socket to non-blocking mode, and write your event loop around a call to `select()`.  The only place the loop should ever block is in the `select()` call, and (assuming you pass in the correct arguments to it) that call will return whenever there is data ready-for-read, and/or whenever there is buffer-space-ready-to-write-to.  (Only request that it return for the latter condition if you actually have data to send, of course)

Comment: Is there an example you could link? I don't totally get what you're saying

Comment: Maybe this article will be helpful:  https://medium.com/vaidikkapoor/understanding-non-blocking-i-o-with-python-part-1-ec31a2e2db9b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while True:
    #receiving

```
client,add=server.accept()
data = client.recv(1024)
str = data.decode('ascii')
print("client is saying: ",str)

#sending

msg = input("server:")
a= msg.encode('ascii')
client.send(a)
```